# Azure DevOps - Is there a way to publish a Fx4.8 WPF application in the pipeline?

Tags: wpf, azure, azure-devops

Is there a way to publish my WPF application in Azure Builds?  In .Net Core projects there is a publish profile, however this is a .Net Framework 4.8 application. It looks like everything gets put in the .csproj file.

In other words, if I right click on my WPF application in Visual Studio 2019, I can click publish. Well, in Azure Builds there is a .NetCoreCLI task to publish for .Net Core apps.

Below are some screen shots of the publish process for WPF .Net Framework 4.8:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Msbuild has a build target called **publish**, when building a WPF project and specifying this target, msbuild will first compile the project and its dependencies (this target depends on the default build target) , and will generate the ClickOnce package and place it in an app.publish folder under the bin directory, which what we will use .For example, the following command:

```
msbuild TodoListClient.csproj /t:publish /p:PublishUrl="$(StorageUrl)" /p:InstallUrl="$(StorageUrl)" /p:Install=true /p:ApplicationVersion=$(Build.BuildNumber) /p:MinimumRequiredVersion=$(Build.BuildNumber) /p:PublisherName="Mohammed Kamil" /p:ProductName="AAD Sample" /p:BootstrapperEnabled=true  /p:IsWebBootstrapper=true /p:SolutionDir="1. Desktop app calls Web API/Desktop-App-calls-Web-API.sln"
```

Setting MSBuild Arguments in Visual Studio Build task:

[image]

Here is a [blog](https://blog.danskingdom.com/continuously-deploy-your-clickonce-application-from-your-build-server/) you can refer to.